# Execute built in function like object_definition('asdf') in a different database

Tags: sql-server

I'm wanting to use built in functions but target objects in a different database.

Example

```
------------------------------------
USE TestDB_1
GO
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION('SOME OBJECT')
UNION
SELECT TestDB_2.SYS.OBJECT_DEFINITION('SOME OBJECT')
------------------------------------
```

I know I can reference sys.sql_modules to get the object definition, I'm asking generically for any of the built in sql functions like db_name(), etc.

Comment: You could try something with `EXECUTE ('<sql>') AT <linked_server>` maybe...

Comment: FWIW, db_name may be a bad example to use, since you can use it in any database context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not reference system functions from other database in SELECT, but you can run select like this

```
use TestDB_1
exec TestDB_2..sp_executesql N'SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(''SOME OBJECT''))'
```